# Exact Online 403 - Forbidden

Tags: exact-online

Im trying to fetch data using REST API of Exact Online, I can have the successful attempt with `SalesInvoiceLines`, `GLAccounts` tables but `SalesOrderLines` throw the error

`status_code=403` and `reason=Forbidden`, Im not sure what is the exact problem. As the link, suggest quite some [errors](https://support.exactonline.com/community/s/knowledge-base#All-All-DNO-Content-respcodeserrorhandling).

Since, all the tables are from same division Im not sure whats going wrong. Tried to look into Exact Online UI but did not understand much.

Someone much more experience with Exact Online and needed permissions could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

## I found 4 main reasons for the 403 error.

**A 403 - Forbidden error message indicates that you have insufficient rights to perform a certain API call.**

### Please check if:

1. The linked Exact Online user has full rights. You must give the user full rights to prevent errors. Make sure you connect a full user with your application. Users with limited rights, like My[Firm] Client users, will not be able to access the API.
2. The linked Exact Online user has access to the company. You can check this through Company name > Master data > Users > Overview. Select a user and click Companies: Access rights in the Monitor] section. Move the company from the No rights section to the Rights section to grant the user access to the company.
3. The application has access to the company. You can check this through Username > My Exact Online > Security Centre. Go to the My App's permissions section and click Manage companies in the Permitted companies column of an application. Move the company from the No rights section to the Rights section to grant the application access to the company.
4. The functionality of your application is compatible with your license. For example, if you have an Accounting license, you cannot work with functionalities that are specifically designed for other license types, such as Sales orders or Projects.